# How to plot an iterative function of y(n+1) against y(n) in order to analyze the convergence of real power towers?

Tags: plotting, functions, iterators, iteration, mathematica-online

I'm new to mathematica and was wondering how to plot an iterative graph for power towers. If there is a power tower y= x^x^x^x^x^x^... we can rewrite it as an iterative equation in the following way:
[image]

Then according to 'The Fractal Boundary of the
Power Tower Function
Peter Lynch, School of Mathematics & Statistics
University College Dublin':

[image]

I want to plot y(n+1) against y(n) using mathematica as they have done in this paper to get graphs like this:

[image]

[image: The strange properties of the infinite power tower by Luca Moroni]

How exactly do I plot these graphs using mathematica and get the cobwebs to show up?

Comment: Hi searching cobweb in the search box here I found 12 results. The one with the highest score seems to be this one: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61323/86543

Comment: There is also a resource function here: https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CobwebPlot/ but I have not used it myself. Note that resource functions are made by community members so consider testing it first.

Comment: Typing cobweb mathematica on google you can find other links such as https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/CobwebModel/ or https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/153946

Comment: You write: "I want to plot y(n+1) against y(n)".  y(n) is a function of x.  y(n)(x). What exactly do you want?

Comment: The block of 4 plots above are just plots of $y(x)=e^{\xi x}$ and $y(x)=x$.  You can start by simply plotting these for example code `Plot[{x,Exp[-0.25 x]},{x,0,6},PlotRange->6]`.  Next enter `Plot[{x, Exp[0.23 x]}, {x, 0, 15}, PlotRange -> {{0, 15}, {0, 15}}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1`' and then start to create the stair steps.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started.

```
(* function to plot: *)
f = Exp[0.33 #] &  
(* describe arrows: *)
nsteps = 5
xs = NestList[f, 4, nsteps]
pts = Partition[Riffle[xs, xs], 2, 1]
arrows = Arrow /@ Partition[pts, 2, 1]
Length@arrows
g = Graphics[{
    {Darker[Green, 0.7], Arrowheads[0.02], arrows},
    HalfLine[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]
    }];
(* create function plot: *)
plt = Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 5},
  Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AspectRatio -> 1]
(* combine function plot and arrows *)
Show[plt, g]
```

[image]